# Why does forEach change my Boolean Value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am making a movie database with 3 movies. I want to make a function that takes an argument (array) and console.log("You have watched this movie") when "haveSeen: true"

```
var movies = [
     {
      title: ...,
      haveSeen: true
     },
     {
      title: ...,
      haveSeen: true
     },
     {
      title: ...,
      haveSeen: false
     }
]




 function display(arr) {
  arr.forEach(function(element) {
    if(element.haveSeen = true) {
      console.log("You have watched this movie")
    }
  })
}
```

When i run "display(movies)" in the console. The console will change all Boolean values of haveSeen to "true". Why? I want the console to only console.log two times because I have only set two movies to "haveSeen: true"

Comment: `if(element.haveSeen = true)` should be `if(element.haveSeen === true)` or just `if(element.haveSeen)`? `=` is the _assignment_ operator, so it should come as no surprise that your properties are assigned to `true`.

Comment: @Xufox of course i totally forgot! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that in your function, you have this line:

```
if(element.haveSeen = true) {
```

The single `=` is the assignment operator, used only when assigning values to variables. Change this to `===` and it'll work:

```
if(element.haveSeen === true) {
```

or because it's Boolean, remove the comparison entirely:

```
if(element.haveSeen) {
```

Comment: The equivalence == operator is usually discouraged in favour of the equals === operator.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the difference between the assignment operator = the equivalence operator == and the equals operator ===.

let x = 1;
if (x = 2) will always be truthy as you just assigned 2 to x and 2 is truthy.

The === operator is what you want to use when testing if something is equal to something else.

if (x === 1) is true and (x === 2) is false.

The == equivalence operator is another thing that you might see people use but many coding standards discourage it's use as the result might not always be what you expect. As in (2 == '2') is true as in the integer 2 is equivalent to the string 2 but they are not equal in the (2 === '2') sense.

Seeing that you are testing a boolean value you don't need any operator and can just use

```
if (element.haveSeen)
```

Comment: == performs type coercion, === checks if both type and value are equal.